# Socket.IO Ping random website to check online status

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm building Node/Vue application.

And currently, I'm having problem with `socket.io-client`

I'm trying to ping a random website to check its status( to check if it is online or offline)

For Example, I have geoserver running on some address, but when I try to connect I get server responds with status 404

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://geoserver:5588/');
```

I expect to do HTTP pooling with socket.io but for some reason, it seems it is not working ??

Comment: Are you sure, you want to connect a websocket through the HTTP protocol ?

Comment: Well not sure, I'm trying to check if my geoserver ( or any other website: google, facebook)  is online and keep that connection open until it goes offline, then try to reconnect again ... that's why I try to use socketIO

Comment: Is there some better way to check if some website or service is online ???

Comment: You could use a module that will send an ICMP packet (a ping). But since JS cannot send raw packets, the modules that you can use will use native code, and may behave differently depending on the OS. And can only be used through Node, not front-end (unless you are using electron or an equivalent)

Comment: Thanx for replying :). I'm using an electron as a desktop. How can I do that trough electron or node ? Also, I would need to keep the status of the server (offline/online) up to date, in case the server goes offline, I would have to show that its offline, and again when online to show that its online ???